# recover data ajax symfony

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I have a sql query in the symfony controller that returns me an array and I want to recover the data via ajax

```
  $statement = $connection->prepare("select name, first name from Contact WHERE name LIKE 'aaaa'");
    //$statement->bindValue('id', 123);
    $statement->execute();
    $results = $statement->fetchAll();
```

this request gets a array (registration list)

how I can treat using ajax result this is what I do but it does not work

```
success: function(data) {
            if (data != ''){
                $ulSub = $("#res");

                $.each(data, function (i,item) {
                    $ulSub.append( // append directly here
                            '<li class="ui-widget-content">' +dataa.nom, +dataa.prenom +'</li>');
                });
            }
```

I want to display the result in an html list

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved, I added:

```
 if (data != ''){
                $ulSub = $("#res");

                $.each(data.dataa, function (i,item) {
                    $ulSub.append( // append directly here
                            '<li class="ui-widget-content">' +item.nom +'</li>');
                });
            }
```

I needed to add `$.each(data.dataa, function (i,item)`.